# Fake Video Interference in Video Sequence Editing

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, video, effects

How can I create fake video interference in clips placed in Blender's Video Sequence Editor? For example, I would want the image to shift every now and then, as well as switch, in a sort of old-TV style, between video clips.

A good example of what I'm looking for would be [this Blender created video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKEdb_ZEJCk), but I have no idea how the person went about doing it. However, I'm sure you can think of any moment in a TV show or movie when a TV or computer screen is displaying one image, then someone cuts or "hacks" in, and the image is replaced.

I expect something like this would require use of the Node Editor?

Comment: Im imagining an x/y transform of the rgb channels with a blur of some sort. But I never tried it.

Comment: Never done this but I shouldn't imagine it would be to hard.  They'd probably need to be manually keyframed where x/y transformations were being jumped between etc.  Disptorted analogue pictures such as minor sync loss could be easily done using a textured plane in the 3D window and shape keys to stretch bits and pieces here and there, all jumped suddenly to emulate static interference.  The options in the VSE might be a little limited compared to what you can do to a textured plane.  Didn't see anything resembling TV interference in your link, so I'm just guessing what it is you're after.